# preview page for uploaded image

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am making a multiple images upload process; I want user to preview their chose images and add some description for images. In here, I make a collection view inside a table view, I want the images show in collection view cell, but I don’t know what I should code to call the images that user picked.

This is image picker controller

```
    @objc func btnClick() {
    let picker = YPImagePicker(configuration: config)
       
        picker.didFinishPicking { [unowned picker] items, _ in
            if let photo = items.singlePhoto {
                print(photo.fromCamera) // Image source (camera or library)
                print(photo.image) // Final image selected by the user
                print(photo.originalImage) // original image selected by the user, unfiltered
                print(photo.modifiedImage) // Transformed image, can be nil
                print(photo.exifMeta) // Print exif meta data of original image.
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        picker.didFinishPicking { [unowned picker] items, cancelled in
            for item in items {
                switch item {
                case .photo(let photo):
                    print(photo)
                case .video(let video):
                    print(video)
                }
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

performSegue(withIdentifier: "UploadTableViewController", sender: nil)
```

here is in the tableView controller

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("UploadCollectionViewCell",
        forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.image?.UIImageView = 
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assign the image to your collection view cell in **cellForItemAt:indexPath**. So do something like:

```
cell.imageView.image =  items[indexPath.row]
```

What else is missing is that once you have picked an image you have to update the **collectionView**. So just reload it by calling:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In CellForRowAt, it is necessary to set the corresponding Image in UIImageView of cell.

```
cell.image = imageData[indexPath.item]
```

`imageData` is a group of Image data that User can select.

Then reload collectionView at any time.

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

example code.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
　　　　　　　　　　　　cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
　　let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("UploadCollectionViewCell",
    forIndexPath: indexPath)
　　cell.image = imageData[indexPath.item]
　　// It works with either item or row. But for CollectionView, .item is preferable.
　　collectionView.reloadData()
　　return cell
}
```

Comment: actually my imageData is not from my assets, it should came from personal uploaded image, you can think it like a camera or a photo library, then how can I define imageData to be personal selected images. Or say it more clear, I want it to be a preview before upload to firebase

Comment: Do you have a sample UI?
I can't really imagine how to implement it.

Comment: like instagram upload image function, I have already developed the image picker session and now I want an preview page before upload to firebase.